# How can I remove the Mac shortcut for apple shift F?

Tags: macos

I want to set a program's shortcut for apple-shift-F. My new MacBook X.10 says apple-shift-F is being used. Looks like it is in use with Finder's presentation mode. How can I remove the shortcut, so that I can add it somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

You can't strictly *remove* the existing shortcut, but you can change it into something else, which will free it up for the function you need.

However… is it quite possible to use the same shortcut on more than one app, as only the frontmost app will respond to it at any given time.

Comment: The app is Divvy. It won't let me assign the shortcut for some reason because it thinks it is being used.